# Is it possible to understand which block(try or catch) was called before finally block?

Tags: c#

I have a try-catch-finally block like below and I need to log the process's result in the finally block. So I need to know the result in finally block to be able to do it.

```cs
var isSucceed = false;
        
try
{
    Do();
    
    isSucceed = true;
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    isSucceed = false;
}
finally
{
    _logger.LogInformation($"The process has been completed. Is Succeed = {isSucceed}");
}
```

So is there any property or method which provides if try block was called?

```cs
try
{
    Do();           
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
}
finally
{
    var isSucceed = <isTryCalled>;
    _logger.LogInformation($"The process has been completed. Is Succeed = {isSucceed}");
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with the first one? To me it looks like that should work. The `isSucceed = false;` in the catch block should be redundant, if the assignment in the try block is the last instruction (or at least after the last one that can throw)

Comment: *"is there any property or method which provides if try block was called?"* No.

Comment: Also, you don't need to set `isSucceed = false` in the `catch` block, since that's the initial value.

Comment: "it did not work" in a log is not useful.  "It worked" is not very useful either.  Log the exception, you'll need it some day soon.

Answer (score 2):

No - but you can safe the exception beforehand:

```cs
Exception error;
try
{
    Do();
}
catch (ArgumentNullException ex)
{
    // Safe the ex
    error = ex;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Safe the ex
    error = ex;
}
finally
{
    var isSucceed = error == null;
    if (isSucceed)
        _logger.LogInformation($"The process has been completed successfully");
    else
        _logger.LogError("The process faulted.", error);
}
```

Comment: The OP already has a method for determining whether or not the `try` or `catch` was the last to run before entering the `finally` block. The question is whether or not there is a property or method that will give that information without creating a variable to track it.

Comment: @RufusL thats why i said 'no' :). I get what you're saying, i was just thinking what OP was likely aiming for and that is what i based the rest of my answer on. Perhaps i should make less assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

The first piece of code you have seems to do what you want very well, but could probably do with some minimisation<sup>(a)</sup>:

```
var succeeded = true;
try {
    Do();
} catch(Exception ex) {
    succeeded = false;
} finally {
    // succeeded is false if exception happened.
}
```

But, to be honest, if you want to do something on exception, why not just do it in the exception block?

In any case, C# does not provide this information, you will have to maintain it yourself, as per the example.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> It *may* be preferable, in the case where you may add future exceptions, to assume failure and flag success at the end of the `try` block. That way, you don't have to remember to flag failure in every single `except` block. That option would be a minor change:

```
var succeeded = false;
try {
    Do();
    succeeded = true;
} catch(Exception1 ex) {
    // No need to change succeeded here.
} catch(Exception2 ex) {
    // Or here.
} catch(Exception3 ex) {
    // Or, yes, you guessed it, here either :-)
} finally {
    // succeeded is false if exception happened.
}
```

Of course, once you get to that point, you may also want to know *which* `except` block was triggered, so a simple boolean flag will not suffice. An enumeration is one possibility, another is storing the exception itself. Both of these would be initialised to "no exception" before the `try` block and then set to a specific value in each `except` block.

In that case, this footnoted solution (assuming a failure then having the `try` block flag success at the end) wouldn't work since you can't really assume a *specific* failure.

Comment: @AluanHaddad: of course it assumes success. That's because failure is defined as an exception occurring. If that happens, succeeded will be false.

Comment: I suppose it doesn't matter.

Comment: Woudln't it make more sense to reverse the logic, e.g `var succeeded = false` if in the future the op wants to add logic to handle a specific exception they will have to remember to fix succeded

Comment: @johnny5: that *is* actually a good point, added that as an addendum. Thanks.